# Network url for tortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've created my repository with tortoiseSVN which is working fine on my local, I am able to import my project and checkout it successfully, but when I am trying to do it on network I am not getting any success.

I followed tutorial to configure my network settings on that(try with proxy and no proxy and setting plink path), it is using same proxy settings that my browsers are running currently, still no relief.

I also tried all combination from forward and backward slash(/////, ///\, ///) with http, https, file and ssl but no response from all of these..

Link that putting while check it out is : `file:///ip_address/E:/trunk/repository...` which is same when I am checkout from my local and tried it with all above mention configuration. Do we required putty for it or it should work with this.. Please advice

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache) ? this may help you.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache

Answer (score 1):

IMHO easiest way for setup remote SVN repository - VisualSVNServer.